# jquery - change value, and re-read back into second function

Tags: jquery

How can I update a value using jquery, and then re-read that value back in another function.

Example:
I have two buttons:

```
<span id="btn1" data-cust="1">BUTTON 1</span>
</br></br>
<span id="btn2">BUTTON2</span>
```

I then have two jquery functions:

```
btn1=function()
{
    $('body').on('click','#btn1',function()
    {
        dc=$('#btn1').data('cust'); //get the value of btn1
        alert(dc);                  //Report the value of btn1
        $('#btn1').attr('data-cust',0);  //Change the value of btn1 to 0
    })
}

btn2=function()
{
    $('body').on('click','#btn2',function()
    {
        dc2=$('#btn1').data('cust'); //get the current value of btn1
        alert(dc2);                  //report the current value of btn1
    })
}
```

As you can see, when I press `BTN1` it changes the data attribute of `#btn1` to 0.

Then I press `BTN2`, looking to pick up the new value of 0, but instead I get the old value of 1.

I tried using `$('#btn1').data('cust',0)` but that doesn't change the attribute, or get picked up by the second function.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So do you call btn1() and btn2() ?? Weird set up

Comment: Why are you using attr to set data? And you use dc2 and alert dc

Comment: You don't report the current value you report what you stored in your variable.

Comment: That's a really weird way to do what you say you're after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be consistent with your use of `.data()` vs `.attr('data', ...)`. This is because while `.data()` can read from both jQuery's internal data store *AND* the HTML5 `data-` attribute, the `.attr('data', ...)` method can only read from and write to HTML5 `data-` attribute.

You shouldn't worry about the HTML5 `data-` attribute not updating: because `.data()` does not update it. However, rest assured that it is being stored properly in the object reference. If you want to depend on jQuery's internal data store completely, then use `.data()` throughout your code:

```js
$('body').on('click', '#btn1', function() {
  dc = $('#btn1').data('cust'); //get the value of btn1
  console.log(dc); //Report the value of btn1
  $('#btn1').data('cust', 0); //Change the value of btn1 to 0
})

$('body').on('click', '#btn2', function() {
  dc2 = $('#btn1').data('cust'); //get the current value of btn1
  console.log(dc2); //report the current value of btn1
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="btn1" data-cust="1">BUTTON 1</span>
<br /><br />
<span id="btn2">BUTTON2</span>
```

However, if it is important that the `data-cust` attribute is updated in the DOM (maybe because other plugins or part of your code relies on reading the HTML5 data attribute, then use `.attr('data', ...)` instead:

```js
$('body').on('click', '#btn1', function() {
  dc = $('#btn1').attr('data-cust'); //get the value of btn1
  console.log(dc); //Report the value of btn1
  $('#btn1').attr('data-cust', 0); //Change the value of btn1 to 0
})

$('body').on('click', '#btn2', function() {
  dc2 = $('#btn1').attr('data-cust'); //get the current value of btn1
  console.log(dc2); //report the current value of btn1
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="btn1" data-cust="1">BUTTON 1</span>
<br /><br />
<span id="btn2">BUTTON2</span>
```